# How to use CodeMirror addon definitions from @types/codemirror?

Tags: typescript, codemirror

The CodeMirror TypeScript types ([@types/codemirror](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/types/codemirror)) are arranged in a few parts. The main `index.d.ts` file contains definitions for the core editor, while the `addon` folder contains definitions for all the different CodeMirror addons.

Addons are loaded dynamically. For example, normally it would not be valid to try to set the "placeholder" option:

```js
CodeMirror.setOption("placeholder", "hello")
```

But if you include

```js
require("codemirror/addon/display/placeholder");
```

then the addon will be included and this option will be available.

However, I'm baffled by how to tell TypeScript about this. If you look at [@types/codemirror/addon/display/placeholder.d.ts](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/codemirror/addon/display/placeholder.d.ts), you can see that it extends the `EditorConfiguration`:

```js
import '../../';

declare module '../../' {
    interface EditorConfiguration {
        /**
         * Adds a placeholder option that can be used to make content appear in the editor when it is empty and not focused.
         * It can hold either a string or a DOM node. Also gives the editor a CodeMirror-empty CSS class whenever it doesn't contain any text.
         */
        placeholder?: string | Node | undefined;
    }
}
```

But, how am I supposed to import this `d.ts` file and tell it that a given CodeMirror instance has the addon loaded? I was hoping that a simple `import "codemirror/addon/display/placeholder";` would suffice but it doesn't seem to work. I also tried a `/// <reference types="..." />` comment but that didn't work either.

Comment: I did manage to make this work for a CodeMirror editor instance, but I still can't figure it out for methods on the global `CodeMirror` object (such as the `requireMode` function provided by the `loadmode.js` addon).